# Workaround to extend limited screen real-estate on Windows?

Tags: windows, resolution

I need a means to use a software tool that requires at least 900 pixels of vertical resolution (as in, the "OK" button to save settings won't be reachable on smaller displays) on a laptop/projector with only 768 pixels of vertical resolution for a training session. So far the only workaround that's been suggested is to memorize the number of tab stops to reach the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons.

Any suggestions on a better workaround? What I'd like to see is a utility that would let me treat the physical display as a 1024x768 view port into a larger, virtual display area. Does anything like that exist? Anything else that might help?

Answer (score 2):

For me, replacing the monitor driver with "Digital Flat Panel (1280x1024)" has worked since the days of Windows 95 OSR 2.1. Then, set the resolution to that level in display properties. Since LCD resolutions are fixed, you will end up with a desktop that is larger than what the monitor can display and you will be able to scroll around.

I am writing this post on laptop with an LCD panel whose native resolution is 1280x800 with monitor driver set to "Digital Flat Panel (1280x1024)" and my desktop size is 1280x1024.

[image]

**Update:** On Windows XP, go to the "Settings" tab in "Display Properties". Click "Advanced" and select the "Monitor" tab. I am assuming your monitor is listed as "Plug and Play Monitor". We will change it to "Digital Flat Panel (1280x1024)".

First, click "Properties" in the "Monitor" tab. Then, select the "Driver" tab and click "Update Driver". Select the option **not** to check Windows update. Then, choose "Install from Specific Location" and select "Don't search. I will choose the driver to install".

On the following screen, deselect "Show Compatible Hardware". Under the "Manufacturer" column, click "(Standard monitor types)". Under the "Model" column, select one of the "Digital Flat Panel" types that is suitable for you. Click "Next".

Now, if you go back to "Display Properties", you will be able to select a resolution that is greater than the resolution of your laptop's LCD panel. The desktop will not fit the screen, but you will be able to scroll around.

Of course, I cannot guarantee that this will work with any given external projector but I personally have not had any problems using this technique with a variety of devices in various classrooms over the years. I also cannot say anything about Windows Vista or Windows 7 because I have not used them at all.

You might first want to try this without connecting to any external displays. Note that this technique will not work with CRTs.

Comment: It would be nice to know why this was downvoted. Is there a problem that I am not aware of?

Comment: I wasn't the one who down voted this, but I can guess; there isn't enough information.

This sounds like a good solution to the problem. I thought I'd try it as it sounds like a good trick to have in case I come across a poor projector. However, I can't figure out how to change the monitor driver. I don't have a Digital Flat Panel driver installed by default.

Perhaps you could post more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [altdrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/), a simple utility, to move the window upwards off the top of the screen, so you can see / click on the buttons at the bottom.